# How to create a map without duplicate values from a map that contains duplicate values?

Tags: apex, map, collection

I have a Map which contains the following entries:

- <1, Developer>
- <2, Admin>
- <3, Manager>
- <4, Admin>
- <5, Developer>
- <6, Sales>

I need a new Map which shouldn't have the repeating values' entries, i.e it should look like :

- <3,Manager>
- <6,Sales>

(As Developer and Admin was repeating, it shouldn't appear in the new map).

Comment: Hi Sakashi - welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] for getting the most from the Community. We're here to help but it would be great if you showed in code what you have tried. Use [edit] to amend your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to make two passes over the data. The first pass to find the non-duplicated values, and the second to make the new map. Here's what that would look like:

```
Set<String> values = new Set<String>(), // Unique values
  dupValues = new Set<String>(); // Values that were duplicated
for(String value: originalMap.values()) {
  // add returns false when Set was not modified; this would be a duplicate
  if(!values.add(value)) { 
    dupValues.add(value);
  }
}
values.removeAll(dupValues);
Map<Integer, String> remainingValueMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
for(Integer key: originalMap.keySet()) {
  // Check all key-value pairs.
  String value = originalMap.get(key);
  if(values.contains(value)) { // This value was unique
    remainingValueMap.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not know about Set.add() returning the boolean value - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with your key and value. Use this class as your composite key. You will need to define an equals and hashcode function as well.